# SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet() stopped working

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet() for several years now, in order to visually switch between sheets in the UI.  Since today this is not functioning anymore. I cannot switch to another sheet using this method. With none of several scripts and spreadsheets that I use.
Any reason why? Or can I use an alternative to force a certain sheet to be displayed in the UI? This is what used to work correctly, but not anymore:

```
function ShowCalculation() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Calculation"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Known issue:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5519

Until it gets fixed, you can try the following code:

```
function ShowCalculation() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 ss.getSheetByName("Calculation").getRange('A1').activate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kishan. I will keep your answer in mind for the next time! But it all works again.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it works again. Nothing changed in my scripts. Has obviously been a google issue.